# How to start Activity in adapter?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, adapter

I have a ListActivity with my customized adapter and inside each of the view, it may have some buttons, in which I need to implement `OnClickListener`. I need to implement the `OnClickListener` in the adapter. However, I don't know how to call the function like `startActivity()` or `setResult()`. Since the adapter doesn't extend to Activity.

So what is the best way to solve this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 204, accepted):

Just pass in the current Context to the Adapter constructor and store it as a field. Then inside the onClick you can use that context to call startActivity().

pseudo-code

```
public class MyAdapter extends Adapter {
     private Context context;

     public MyAdapter(Context context) {
          this.context = context;     
     }

     public View getView(...){
         View v;
         v.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
             void onClick() {
                 context.startActivity(...);
             }
         });
     }
}
```

Comment: but one more question, what if I need to call setResult? because i need to call onActivityResult(...) function in my activity.  thanks for your help.

Comment: If you want to return some result from the child activity, you need to start the activity with startActivityForResult instead of StartActivity, and override onActivityResult (which is called after the child activity ends).

Comment: @RobbyPond Context does not have startActivityForResult() !
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html

Comment: you can cast context like that: ((Activity) context).startActivityForResults(intent,0);

Comment: Is there a way to putExtra and Finish() current activity?

Answer (score 68):

When implementing the `onClickListener`, you can use `v.getContext.startActivity`.

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {                  
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        v.getContext().startActivity(PUT_YOUR_INTENT_HERE);
    }
});
```

Comment: but one more question, what if I need to call setResult? because i need to call onActivityResult(...) function in my activity. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 32):

```
public class MyAdapter extends Adapter {
     private Context context;      


     public MyAdapter(Context context) {
          this.context = context;         
     }


     public View getView(...){  
         View v;  
         v.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
             void onClick() {
                  Intent intent= new Intent(context, ToActivity.class); 
                   intent.putExtra("your_extra","your_class_value");
                 context.startActivity(intent);
             }
         });
     }
}
```

Comment: An old thread but adding for newer search results: this callback from adapter goes anti design pattern as Intents should be created and executed within activities listeners are best for this used case.

Answer (score 14):

For newer versions of sdk you have to set flag activity task.

```
public void onClick(View v)
 {
     Intent myactivity = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), OtherActivity.class);
     myactivity.addFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
     context.getApplicationContext().startActivity(myactivity);
 }
```

Comment: This is the real answer due to:  context.getApplicationContext().startActivity(myactivity);  If you use alone context.startActivity(intent) it won't work! Just solve the issue this way for kotlin on android

Answer (score 4):

Simple way to start activity in Adopter's button onClickListener:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(),Event_Member_list.class);                    myIntent.putExtra("intVariableName", eventsList.get(position).getEvent_id());
                view.getContext().startActivity(myIntent);
```

Answer (score 2):

callback from adapter to activity can be done using registering listener in form of interface:
 Make an interface:

```
      public MyInterface{
         public void  yourmethod(//incase needs parameters );
         }
```

In Adapter Let's Say MyAdapter:

```
    public MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
       private MyInterface listener;

    MyAdapter(Context context){
        try {
            this. listener = (( MyInterface ) context);
              } catch (ClassCastException e) {
               throw new ClassCastException("Activity must implement MyInterface");
          }
```

//do this  where u need to fire listener
          l

```
          try {
                listener . yourmethod ();
            } catch (ClassCastException exception) {
               // do something
            }

      In Activity Implement your method:


         MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MyInterface{

                yourmethod(){
                //do whatever you want
                     }
                     }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
```

view - `public void onClick(View view)` `OnClick` of image.

Answer (score 1):

**First Solution:**

You can call start activity inside your adapter like this:

```
public class YourAdapter extends Adapter {
     private Context context;

     public YourAdapter(Context context) {
          this.context = context;     
     }

     public View getView(...){
         View v;
         v.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
             void onClick() {
                 context.startActivity(...);
             }
         });
     }
}
```

**Second Solution:**

You can call `onClickListener` of your button out of the `YourAdapter` class. Follow these steps:

Craete an interface like this:

```
public YourInterface{
         public void  yourMethod(args...);
}
```

Then inside your adapter:

```
    public YourAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
               private YourInterface listener;

           public YourAdapter (Context context, YourInterface listener){
                    this.listener = listener;
                    this.context = context;
           }

           public View getView(...){
                View v;
         v.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
             void onClick() {
                 listener.yourMethod(args);
             }
         });
}
```

And where you initiate yourAdapter will be like this:

```
YourAdapter adapter = new YourAdapter(getContext(), (args) -> {
            startActivity(...);
        });
```

This [link](https://medium.com/@CodyEngel/4-ways-to-implement-onclicklistener-on-android-9b956cbd2928) can be useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect on url instead of activity from your adapter class  then **pass context of with startactivity.**

```
btnInstall.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(link));
                intent.setData(Uri.parse(link));
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```