# android start Activity in adapter (transition animiation direction problem)

Tags: java, android, android-activity, adapter, transition

I was having the problem in here : [How to start Activity in adapter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4197135/how-to-start-activity-in-adapter) . however, i would like to modify the transition animation direction. since, inside an adapter, you cannot call overridePendingTransition(). So do you guys know how to do it by using context and intent?

also, i have an activity using my customized adapter, and do you guys know how to call my own function in activity from the adapter?

thank you so much!
penny

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you need to pass a Context into your adapter, can you override the constructor and pass one in then?

Comment: yes, i have passed the context into the adapter. since context is superclass of activity, context cannot use all the function in activity... that make me stuck.....

Comment: ahh, sorry, I misread your question, why don't you pass the Activity in then?

Comment: damn,,oh , i am such dick head....... thanks a lot you help me out.....thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
((Activity)  context).overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_out_right,R.anim.slide_in_left);
```