# overridePendingTransition on gridview adapter

Tags: android, overriding, adapter, transition, baseadapter

How can I insert `overridePendingTransition` on a `GridView` `Adapter? In this way don't work, without transition startactivity work perfectly

```
bt.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener(){
                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                        final String selectedPad = Drum.pads[position];
                        Intent modPad = new Intent(v.getContext(), ModifyPad.class);
                        modPad.putExtra("pad", selectedPad);
                        context.startActivity(modPad);
                        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.exit_slid_in, R.anim.exit_slid_out);
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

I've read this post:
[android start Activity in adapter (transition animiation direction problem)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215070/android-start-activity-in-adapter-transition-animiation-direction-problem), and comments related, but I don't know how pass the `Activity` in the `Adapter`. Any help?

Answer (score 23):

Context is the Base Object of Activity ( see: [What is the difference between Activity and Context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6518206/what-is-the-difference-between-activity-and-context) ), 
so I used following:

```
Activity activity = (Activity) mContext;
activity.startActivity(repinIntent);
activity.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.act_start_in_from_right, R.anim.act_start_out_to_left);
```

Refers to: [Getting activity from context in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9891360/getting-activity-from-context-in-android)