# Custom ListActivity and onListItemClick for inside Views

Tags: android, listview, listactivity, android-arrayadapter

I have custom ListView with custom adapter extending ArrayAdapter.
ArrayAdapter is inflating xml with two views:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/filePickerTextView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
        android:focusable="true" android:text="item" />

    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="true" android:src="@drawable/icon"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/filePickerImageView1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_alignRight="@android:id/text1"></ImageView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

In ListActivity method onListItemClick i'm getting RelativeLayout view. What i need is, to know which exact view was clicked (TextView or ImageView). I can get this in adapter by setting listeners, but i need it in ListActivity. The reason is, that i need to raise setResult based on clicked view.

Answer (score 1):

In Custom adapter class you can used below code then click on Textview accordingly you will get toast message and click on imageview then accordingly get toast message.

```
 holder.filePickerImageView1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // toast message;

        }
    });

  holder.filePickerTextView1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // toast message;

        }
    });
```

Comment: As i said in question, i need it in ListActivity, not in adapter. Is there possibility to exchange data between ListActivity and adapter?

Comment: you can set data in listactivity from adapter

Answer (score 1):

After 5 months I'm back to my project and I found solution for my question.
Easiest way is to pass context to custom adapter.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4197364/214081