# Starting a new Activity BaseAdapter

Tags: android

how to start new activity in baseadapter i do the default way to open activity but not work with baseadapter

> Intent intent = new Intent(context,AnotherActivity.class);
>   context.startActivity(intent);

```
 @Override
public View getView(final int p, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View grid;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if (convertView == null) {

        grid = new View(mContext);
        grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview_custom_layout, null);

    } else {
        grid = (View) convertView;
    }
    TextView textView = (TextView) grid.findViewById(R.id.gridview_text);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView)grid.findViewById(R.id.gridview_image);
    textView.setText(string[p]);
    imageView.setImageResource(Imageid[p]);

    imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (p){
                case 0:
                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Clicked Laugh Vote", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case 2:

                    break;
                default:
                    // Do something else
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to start Activity in adapter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4197135/how-to-start-activity-in-adapter)

Comment: did you get any error while starting activity ?

Comment: problem solve thanks

Comment: pls post full adapter code or start activity code from Adapter

Comment: Simply, you need to use the contructor of your adapter with context and LIst, That context u need to use in the startActivity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code to start a new Activity BaseAdapter:

```
imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mContext.startActivity(new Intent(mContext,YourActivity.class))
    }
});
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to explain how to solve the problem and provide the code as an example or reference. Code-only answers can be confusing and lack context.

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent yourIntent = new Intent(mContext,Wukong.class);
                    yourIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
                   mContext.startActivity(yourIntent);
```

Comment: You should explain why you are recommending the above code.